# Removing rows of data frame if number of NA in a column is larger than 3

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a data frame (panel data): `Ctry` column indicates the name of countries in my data frame. In any column (for example: `Carx`) if number of NAs is larger 3; I want to drop the related country in my data fame. For example,

- Country A has 2 NA
- Country B has 4 NA
- Country C has 3 NA

I want to drop country B in my data frame. I have a data frame like this (This is for illustration, my data frame is actually very huge):

```
  Ctry  year   Carx
   A    2000    23
   A    2001    18
   A    2002    20
   A    2003    NA
   A    2004    24
   A    2005    18
   B    2000    NA
   B    2001    NA
   B    2002    NA
   B    2003    NA
   B    2004    18
   B    2005    16
   C    2000    NA
   C    2001    NA
   C    2002    24
   C    2003    21
   C    2004    NA
   C    2005    24
```

I want to create a data frame like this:

```
  Ctry  year   Carx
   A    2000    23
   A    2001    18
   A    2002    20
   A    2003    NA
   A    2004    24
   A    2005    18
   C    2000    NA
   C    2001    NA
   C    2002    24
   C    2003    21
   C    2004    NA
   C    2005    24
```

Comment: You may want to correct your question, I assume you want to remove B, not C.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Ctry B should be removed not C, thank you

Comment: as @beginneR asks: how big is "very huge"?  How many rows, columns?

Comment: maybe it is not a big data set for R, :) it is about 11800 rows, 9 columns

Answer (score 3):

A fairly straightforward way in base R is to use `sum(is.na(.))` along with `ave`, to do the counting, like this:

```
with(mydf, ave(Carx, Ctry, FUN = function(x) sum(is.na(x))))
#  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Once you have that, subsetting is easy:

```
mydf[with(mydf, ave(Carx, Ctry, FUN = function(x) sum(is.na(x)))) <= 3, ]
#    Ctry year Carx
# 1     A 2000   23
# 2     A 2001   18
# 3     A 2002   20
# 4     A 2003   NA
# 5     A 2004   24
# 6     A 2005   18
# 13    C 2000   NA
# 14    C 2001   NA
# 15    C 2002   24
# 16    C 2003   21
# 17    C 2004   NA
# 18    C 2005   24
```

Comment: Thanks for help. What about if I have more than one column. For example, in addition to "Carx", I have also "Barx" and "Tarx" with NAs

Comment: @user3528777, you'll need to be more specific in terms of how you would want to treat such data. Perhaps you would also be interested in `complete.cases`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [by()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/by.html) function to group by `Ctry` and count `NA`'s of each group :

```
DF <- read.csv(
text='Ctry,year,Carx
A,2000,23
A,2001,18
A,2002,20
A,2003,NA
A,2004,24
A,2005,18
B,2000,NA
B,2001,NA
B,2002,NA
B,2003,NA
B,2004,18
B,2005,16
C,2000,NA
C,2001,NA
C,2002,24
C,2003,21
C,2004,NA
C,2005,24',
stringsAsFactors=F)

res <- by(data=DF$Carx,INDICES=DF$Ctry,FUN=function(x)sum(is.na(x)))
validCtry <-names(res)[res <= 3]

DF[DF$Ctry %in% validCtry, ]

#   Ctry year Carx
#1     A 2000   23
#2     A 2001   18
#3     A 2002   20
#4     A 2003   NA
#5     A 2004   24
#6     A 2005   18
#13    C 2000   NA
#14    C 2001   NA
#15    C 2002   24
#16    C 2003   21
#17    C 2004   NA
#18    C 2005   24
```

**EDIT :**

if you have more columns to check, you could adapt the previous code as follows:

```
res <- by(data=DF,INDICES=DF$Ctry,
          FUN=function(x){
                           return(sum(is.na(x$Carx)) <= 3 && 
                                  sum(is.na(x$Barx)) <= 3 && 
                                  sum(is.na(x$Tarx)) <= 3)
                         })
validCtry <- names(res)[res]

DF[DF$Ctry %in% validCtry, ]
```

where, of course, you may change the condition in `FUN` according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention that you data is "very huge" (whatever that means exactly), you could try a solution with `dplyr` and see if it's perhaps faster than the solutions in base R. If the other solutions are fast enough, just ignore this one.

```
require(dplyr)

newdf <- df %.% group_by(Ctry) %.% filter(sum(is.na(Carx)) <= 3)
```